# Can I remove the beans defined in a file from a spring context

Tags: spring

I am creating a Test Suite with 10 Test classes Class1 - Class10

There are beans that i need to load from some xml files. I have in all 14 xml files to load S1.xml - S14.xml. Out of these S1.xml - S5.xml are used by all classes.

S6.xml - S8.xml is used by Class1 - CLass3 only,
S9.xml - S11.xml is used by Class4 - CLass7 only,
S12.xml - S14.xml is used by Class8 - CLass10 only

My test Suite first loads the context with 5 files S1.xml - S5.xml. When the execution of Class1 starts it dynamically loads S6.xml - S8.xml. How can i remove the dynamically beans loaded from these context after Class3 has completed execution and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports [profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) and the [@ActiveProfiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) annotation on test classes for this purpose.